# Synchronized specifier hinders transfer of variable data

Tags: java, synchronized

I recently assembled a program to obtain data serially through the usb port and transfer it to COSM. The data obtained serially through the `serialevent` method wasn't getting passed to the `update` method which is used to upload the aforementioned data on COSM. However after removing the `synchronized` specifier from the signature of the `serialevent` method this problem was solved.

```
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent)//Event handler for Serial communication  
{

    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) 
    {
        try {

            val=input.read();//Variable where data is received.Initialized to 0.
             this.update(78164);  

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Method for upload:

```
private  void update(int feedid) throws PachubeException, IOException ,Exception
{

    Feed f = this.pachube.getFeed(feedid);
   //System.out.println(f==null);
     System.out.println("updating ...");




     f.updateDatastream(8345, (double) val);//Expected value=77,Obtained value=0
     f.updateDatastream(6274, (double) val);//Expected value=77,Obtained value=0
     f.updateDatastream(1044, (double) val);//Expected value=77,Obtained value=0

   System.out.println("updated");

}
```

My question is how was the `synchronized` specifier denying the data present in the variable to pass from the `serialevent` method to `upload` even when i wasn't using multiple threads?

Comment: Is `val` an instance field? Why do you expect it to be 77?

Comment: yes it is. Because i ran it without the `upload` method call, and displayed the value obtained in `serialevent` in the same method itself through system.out.println , and found out that it was 77

Comment: Show use. Before `this.update(78164);`, put a `System.out.println(this.val)`.

Comment: The code you've suggested prints the same value ie 77. Strangely though, when I added the `synchronized` specifier to the corrected code and  incorporated your code the program passed the values without any glitches this time. It seems to be working even in the presence of the `synchronized`  specifier now.

Comment: I doubt `synchronized` had anything to do with it.  Maybe you project was just not recompiled when you ran it with your new changes.

Comment: okay then what do you think caused the problem in the first place? The true value(expected value) was displayed correctly when `System.out.println(this.val)` was placed in the `serialevent` method but not in the `update` method.

Comment: I don't know. Does it work now?

Comment: It does...it started working in the first place when i got rid of the `synchronized` specifier for the `serialEvent` method.